# vim regular expression changing value

Tags: regex, vim

I have pattern `Avg="113.01"` in the text file, when I apply regular expression like as `%s/="/=/g` it changes value `113.01` to `62.31`.

All I am trying to do is remove the double quotes but its changing value of the numbers all over.

Comment: why not use `s/"//g` ?

Comment: i need to retain things like status="" as is. Only convert the numbers within string into numbers. But i am trying to understand why its converting 113.01 to 62.31

Comment: so, if you are trying to extract the numbers, why are you writing *All i am trying to do is remove the double quotes* ?

Comment: i tried above regEx that you have provided, it will still change value 103.01 to 62.31

Comment: don't know how, I don't have this beahavior: https://regex101.com/r/zN82NS/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression should do: `s/="\([0-9.]\{1,\}\)"/=\1/g`.
It looks for number patterns enclosed with double quotes and retain only the number pattern.

I look for the pattern number with `[0-9.]\{1,\}`. It means that every string of number or dot of a minimum length of 1 and no maximum. Backslashes before the brackets are mandatory in regular expressions in order not to be wrongly interpreted by the os. This number pattern is then saved within the parenthesis (also with backslashes) to be reused with the \1 notation in the second part. 
The rest is straightforward.

Comment: why are you back-slashing everything? `s/="([0-9.]{1,})"/=\1/g` is what OP needs ;) or a more concise way : `s/="([0-9.]+)"/=\1/g`, OP told in a comment that he wanted to keep only the number, so he should use: `s/\w+="([0-9.]+)"/\1/g`

Comment: Yes this worked well for me. but you may need to explain bit more about regular expression

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
s/"\([^"]*\)/\1/g
```

to capture everything after the first quote and before the last quote.

Comment: Even using this would change the values of the numbers. i replaces double quotes but at the same time its changing values. Thats the problem i am facing. No solution found yet